# Java Quicksort (array values not changing values when reassigned)

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm, quicksort

**The Problem:** 
I wrote a quicksort algorithm in Java. When I try the case:
{4, 3, 1, 2, 0}, I get {0,2,1,3,4}

So, I started stepping through the debugger to see what was wrong, and noticed that when I get to a certain part in the code, the reassignment of array values is completely ignored (circled in red):

[image]

At this point, it should take intArray[ 1 ] and make it equal to 2, and then make intArray [ 3] equal to the pivot value. However, it completely ignores these two lines of code.

I tried a few other cases (below) to make sure it wasn't a way I was passing variables or something like that (but they worked just fine with the same code):

```
   private final static int[] intArray = new int[]{4, 8, 1, 6, 3, 7, 2, 5};
   private final static int[] intArray = new int[]{11,10,9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1};
   private final static int[] intArray = new int[]{1,2,3,4,5};
```

**Question:**
Is there something about Java array reassignments that I shouldn't be doing here that could be causing a problem? If not, can someone point in the right direction?

**Full Code:**

```
 package quicksort;

/**
 * @date December 4, 2015
 */
public class Quicksort {
    private final static int[] intArray = new int[]{4, 3, 1, 2, 0};


    /**
     * @purpose This method partitions the array and subarrays based on the current pivot point
     * @param pivot
     * @param leftPointer
     * @param rightPointer 
     */
private static void partition(int pivot, int leftPointer, int rightPointer) {

    while (leftPointer <= rightPointer) {
        if (pivot < intArray[rightPointer]) {
            rightPointer--;
        } else if (pivot > intArray[rightPointer]) {
            intArray[leftPointer] = intArray[rightPointer];
            intArray[rightPointer] = pivot;
            leftPointer++;
        } else if (intArray[leftPointer] > pivot) {
            intArray[rightPointer] = intArray[leftPointer];
            intArray[leftPointer] = pivot;
            rightPointer--;
        } else {
            leftPointer++;
        }

    }
    for (int x = 0; x <= intArray.length - 1; x++) {
        System.out.print(intArray[x] + " ");
    }
    System.out.println();

}

/**
 * @purpose This method recursively runs the partition method for the array and subarrays
 * @param pivot
 * @param leftPointer
 * @param rightPointer 
 */
private static void quicksort(int pivot, int leftPointer, int rightPointer) {

    while (rightPointer != 0) {
        partition(intArray[0], 0, rightPointer);
        rightPointer--;
    }

    while (leftPointer != intArray.length - 1) {
        leftPointer++;
        partition(intArray[leftPointer], leftPointer, intArray.length - 1);
    }

}

/**
 * @purpose Runs the Quicksort class
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int leftPointer = 0;
    int rightPointer = intArray.length - 1;
    int pivot = intArray[0];
    quicksort(pivot, leftPointer, rightPointer);

}

}
```

Thanks for any advice!

Comment: (This is not quicksort, as Mateo already answered. It reminds of [shaker sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cocktail_sort)). Please include duplicate values in at least one of your test inputs.

Comment: Okay. Thank you both. I clearly see I misunderstood how to implement the algorithm. However, does that mean that those two lines of code should be skipped when the code is running? That still seems strange to me. Should I post it as a new question without mentioning it is supposed to be quicksort?

Comment: (`Should I post it as a new question without mentioning it is supposed to be quicksort` IMO, you should update the title.) You show a state at _one_ point in time, making it hard to follow what might be going wrong - what have the values of elements [at index] 1 and 3 been (in the same iteration …) reaching the 2nd condition/line 34?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I understand you don't expect that sb presents you a good code, as it can be easily found on the internet. I assume you would like to know, what's wrong with your code.

I can't find any recursion. Quicksort consists in partitioning the array, dividing it into two smaller arrays and quicksorting them (recursively).

Your Quicksort function makes a strange iteration, each time dealing with an array from 0 to sth or from sth to the end, which is not correct. What's more, you call Quicksort on (sth,left,right), but in the definition (or body, I don't know how to name it in English: the part{...}) of Quicksort you deal with larger array, namely from 0 to right. This is very unclear.

The left and right arguments of Quicksort are necessary, since it is called recursively and on each call it works on different part of the array. You call Quicksort only once.

Comment: Thanks for explaining that. I found what I was doing in terms of the values. I wasnt able to duplicate my original error so I must have misunderstood what my problem was (besides not writing a true quicksort algorithm).